# Replicate zirconia material in blender-cycles (tooth material)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I"m trying to replicate the material in the shown image. Can anyone help me, please?
It's called zirconia and used in dental crowns.[image]

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I dont think your link is covering the topic

Comment: hamid.h check this  https://blenderartists.org/t/sss-teeth-shader/702170/17

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/teeth-transparent-material-simulation/702013

Comment: many thanks, I checked the link. I don't know what they used for the textures can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 4):

I've given a try with your tooth, basically it's a mix between a *Diffuse* and a *Glossy* node, then a bit of *Subsurface Scattering* to give it a bit of depth and transparency. Add a *Noise Texture* to give it a bit of bumps, scale it on the Z axis as the strias are rather vertical. You could also try a bit of *Transluncency* at the end if necessary.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great result. I'll try that.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I used when I was doing teeth in Max for almost a year for dental animations. I get electric shocks just thinking about it.

Comment: ah ah you mean these are bad memories? Because of Max or because of the dental work?